# Change column value if value is in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have 2 dataframe as follow:

df1:

```
       Materials      Col2       Col3 ...
1      Wood metal      X          Y
2        Rock          X          Y
3      Rock Metal      X          Y
```

df2:

```
       Mat
1     Metal
2      ...
```

I would like to loop over the first dataframe, if value of Materials contains a word that I can find in df2 then I will change it to 1 so I would get:

df1:

```
        Materials    Col2       Col3 ...
1         1            X          Y
2         0            X          Y
3         1            X          Y
```

Any suggestions ?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#check if Materials column contains any words from df2. This will also handle both lower case and upper case matching

df1.Materials = df1.apply(lambda x: 1 if np.in1d(np.array(x.Materials.lower().split()),df2.Mat.str.lower()).any() else 0, axis=1)

df1
Out[2619]: 
   Materials   Col2  Col3 
1          1      X      Y
2          0      X      Y
3          1      X      Y
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this without using `apply`, you could use `pd.Series.str.contains` and `np.where`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Materials': ['Wood metal', 'Rock', 'Rock Metal'],
                    'Col2': ['X', 'X', 'X'], 'Col3': ['Y', 'Y', 'Y']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Mat': ['Metal']})

df1['Materials'] = np.where(df1['Materials'].str.lower().str.contains('|'.join(df2['Mat']).lower()), 1, 0)
```